# Disabling the default tab when other tabs are selected

Tags: javascript, html

My code has 5 tabs. Initially the first one is selected as default. I want that when the others are selected, the first one should not be selected at that time. Right now whenever other tabs are selected, the first one is highlighted too and when I hover the mouse over it, it does not even give me the hand pointer that appears when selecting the tab. Is there any solution to it?

In the image, when tomorrow is selected, overdue is highlighted as well. (Overdue is my default tab), I don't want it to be highlighted
[image]

Javascript:

```
   <script>
        $(function () {              
                $(".first").tab('show');              
        });            

         $(function () {
          $(".first").click(function (e) {
              $(".section1").toggle();
                $(".section2").hide();
                $(".section3").hide();
                $(".section4").hide();
                $(".section5").hide();
                e.preventDefault();                    
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $(".second").click(function (f) {
                $(".section2").toggle();
                $(".section1").hide();
                $(".section3").hide();
                $(".section4").hide();
                $(".section5").hide();                    
                f.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $(".third").click(function (g) {
                $(".section3").toggle();
                $(".section1").hide();
                $(".section2").hide();
                $(".section4").hide();
                $(".section5").hide();
                g.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $(".fourth").click(function (i) {
                $(".section4").toggle();
                $(".section1").hide();
                $(".section3").hide();
                $(".section2").hide();
                $(".section5").hide();
                i.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $(".fifth").click(function (h) {
                $(".section5").toggle();
                $(".section1").hide();
                $(".section3").hide();
                $(".section4").hide();
                $(".section2").hide();
                h.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
       <li class="first"><a href="#">Over due</a></li>
       <li class="second"><a href="#">Due Today</a></li>
       <li class="third"><a href="#">Due Tomorrow</a></li>
       <li class="fourth"><a href="#">Due This Week</a></li>
       <li class="fifth"><a href="#">Due This Month</a></li>
                               </ul>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? And should the tabs that are not active still be visible or should they disappear completely?

Comment: Do a favor for yourself and do it with framework like bootstrap (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) or jQueryUI (https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: I tried it by using bootstrap, with the same link you entered, my code was messed up

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.nav a').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var index = $('.nav a').index($this);
  
  if (index > 0) {
    $('.content div').hide().eq(index).show();
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
}

.content div {
  display:none;  
}

.content div:first-child {
  display:block;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
   <li><a href="#">Over due</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Due Today</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Due Tomorrow</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Due This Week</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Due This Month</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
  <div>Content 1</div>  
  <div>Content 2</div>
  <div>Content 3</div>
  <div>Content 4</div>
  <div>Content 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li data-target="section1" class="tab first"><a href="#">Over due</a></li>
    <li data-target="section2" class="tab second"><a href="#">Due Today</a></li>
    <li data-target="section3" class="tab third"><a href="#">Due Tomorrow</a></li>
    <li data-target="section4" class="tab fourth"><a href="#">Due This Week</a></li>
    <li data-target="section5" class="tab fifth"><a href="#">Due This Month</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var $tabs = $('.tab');
    $tabs.slice(1).hide();
    $('.tab').click(function () {
        var $target = $('#' + $(this).data('target')).show();
        $tabs.not($target).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more line to your code `$(".first").hide()` in all the functions except `$(".first").click(function(){.........})` So your javascript would be as follows

Javascript:

```
     $(function () {              
            $(".first").tab('show');              
     });            

     $(function () {
      $(".first").click(function (e) {
          $(".section1").toggle();
            $(".section2").hide();
            $(".section3").hide();
            $(".section4").hide();
            $(".section5").hide();
            e.preventDefault();                    
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $(".second").click(function (f) {
            $(".first").hide();
            $(".section2").toggle();
            $(".section1").hide();
            $(".section3").hide();
            $(".section4").hide();
            $(".section5").hide();                    
            f.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $(".third").click(function (g) {
            $(".first").hide();
            $(".section3").toggle();
            $(".section1").hide();
            $(".section2").hide();
            $(".section4").hide();
            $(".section5").hide();
            g.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $(".fourth").click(function (i) {
            $(".first").hide();
            $(".section4").toggle();
            $(".section1").hide();
            $(".section3").hide();
            $(".section2").hide();
            $(".section5").hide();
            i.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Suggestion please try jquery ui tabs or bootstrap tabs instead of making your own they provide a lots of good support to all these kind of features.

Comment: Okay what happens if you remove  `$(".first").click(function (e) {........ });` from your script

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating things here. All you would need to do is add and remove the appropriate css classes to show and hide the current active tab.

You definitely do not need to add a `click` event listener to each and every tab link. You can handle all of the actions in one `click` event listener.

Here is an example, trying to mimic your css a bit. Sure you will get the idea.

```js
(function (jQuery) {
  var tabLinks = $('.nav-tabs').find('a'),
      tabContent = $('.tab-content');

  function showTab(evt) {
    var tabToShow = $(this).attr('href'),
        prevTab = tabContent.children('.show-tab');
    tabLinks.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    prevTab.removeClass('show-tab');
    tabContent.find(tabToShow).addClass('show-tab');
    evt.preventDefault();
  }

  tabLinks.on('click', showTab);
}($));
```

```css
.container {
  color: #555;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 600px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-tabs:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav-tabs li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-tabs li a {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c7bc8;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-tabs li a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav-tabs .active {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  color: #555;
}

.nav-tabs .active:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.tab-content {
  position: relative;
}

.tab-content div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab-content div.show-tab {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
    <li><a class="active" href="#over-due">Over due</a></li>
    <li><a href="#due-today">Due Today</a></li>
    <li><a href="#due-tomorrow">Due Tomorrow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#due-this-week">Due This Week</a></li>
    <li><a href="#due-this-month">Due This Month</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="show-tab" id="over-due">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo nobis voluptas, porro quos! Animi necessitatibus, perferendis ullam aliquam voluptatem itaque, expedita distinctio unde repudiandae, enim voluptas, similique. Sed, illo saepe!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="due-today">
      <p>Something for today.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="due-tomorrow">
      <p>Something for tomorrow.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="due-this-week">
      <p>Something for this week.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="due-this-month">
      <p>Something for this month.</p>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```